# Powermail 7.3 receiver attachment from hidden input field

Tags: typo3, powermail

i need a multiple file upload with drag&drop in a powermail form. I made it with jQuery that added the files to a hidden iput field. Does anyone know how i can attach these files to the receiver email. i tried with typoscript ..addAttachment and ...data = GP:tx_powermail... but it seems to work only with a static file.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to use the Powermail default https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/stable/ForEditors/AddANewForm/FieldFile/Index.html - then extend the frontend from there.

Comment: The file upload field works if you choose different files at once. If you choose one after an other from different folders, the previous once are overwritten.... Seems to be a default html5 behavior

Comment: Ok. If you have the upload functionality with the default example, you can get your fancy uploader to set the form fields in the same way.